# Rule violations?

Tags: discussion

[This user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16165/saga12) is suspendend for rule violations. But why? I don't see anything wrong. The user has some downvoted questions, but poor questions should lead to a question ban, not to a suspension.

So, why is this user suspended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How coincidental; I just posted a meta post on this: [How do I respond to a suspected sockpuppet situation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/967/3808)

> [This
>   user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16123/utkarsh-asian-verma)
>   is violating the rules - he is asking a bunch of terrible questions
>   with these two sockpuppets:
>   [A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16137/user16137),
>   [B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16165/saga12). Notice that
>   the sockpuppets I linked have 3 and 4 questions respectively, each of
>   which has been answered by this user (and accepted).

That user is a sockpuppet. Frankly, I'm suprised it still exists at all; I think it should be nuked.

Comment: I see, all questions of the suspended user were answered by the sock-puppeteer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We will never comment publicly on why a user is suspended. This is a matter of Stack Exchange policy.

I will say that in cases of sockpuppetry the main account is suspended and all others destroyed. You may draw what conclusions you like from that as far as Doorknobs answer is concerned.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that policy.