# How do I respond to a suspected sockpuppet situation

Tags: support

I think I have detected a case of sockpuppetry, and have already flagged one of the posts asking for moderator action but this has not occurred.

How could we go about fixing this? I've already flagged a post of his as "other," but our three moderators have not been seen for 40 minutes, 3 hours, and a day.

Comment: As a general rule, you should not post to meta focused on other users. Doing so usually leads to on-going conflict.

Comment: @dmckee Alright, sorry. I assume you're handling my two "other" flags now? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak to the other moderators, but I have been keeping an eye on the current situation.

The usual sanctions for sockpuppetry are difficult to reverse,<sup>1</sup> so I don't take them lightly or apply them without pretty good evidence. This can result in a delay.

Moderators have various tools not available to the ordinary users, and we look for pretty strong evidence before acting.

In the mean time, less sophisticated cheaters often post hasty or ill-prepared material when trying to boost their score through sockpuppetry, so a short-term action is to treat that content like, well, hasty or ill-prepared material. The big advantage of this strategy is that applied uniformly is promotes quality on the site regardless of the reality of the sockpuppet claim.

---

<sup>1</sup> Most moderator actions can be reversed---in many cases this makes it as if they never happened, which lets us take a *"due diligence and take your best guess"* approach to applying them. A few drastic action taken on accounts are difficult or even impossible to reverse. We try not to make mistakes with those.